# Python - Reading an integer from a file and replacing it on the same file after its manipulation

Tags: python-3.4

I am trying to read a number from a text file, add 1 to this number and then overwrite the old number with the new number in python

```
file = open('group_count','w+')# opens the text file which contains a number
groupcount = file.read()    # reads the number
i = int(groupcount)     # supposed to convert the number from the text file to an interger
groupcountnew=groupcount+1  # supposed to 'add one' to that number in the text file
file.write(groupcountnew) # will write that new number to the text file, overriding the original number
```

It is not working, can someone help please !

Comment: Trying to overwrite data in a specific place in a file is not simple. The easiest thing to do is write a new file then delete the old file and rename the new file.

Comment: In the text file it only actually contains the one number which I am trying to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet should work:

```
# opening the source file
with open('group_count.txt','r') as f:
    # reading the number
    data=f.read()

    #calculating the new number
    new_data = int(data) + 1 

# writing the new number on the same file
with open('group_count.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(str(new_data))
```

Comment: With this I get an error saying that it cannot convert string to float :(

Comment: I modified the code to make directly the conversion string to int

Comment: With this new edit I get this error when it is ran  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I tested the program on an online editor and it was working... can you please post the content of your txt file? [and be sure to save it before?]

Comment: I have managed to get it to work like this; def OPENFILE():
    file = open('group_count.txt','r')
    groupcount = int(file.read())
    file.close()
    groupcountnew=groupcount+1
    file = open('group_count.txt','w')
    file.write(str(groupcountnew))
    file.close()

OPENFILE()

Comment: Thanks for your help though mate, im sure your code was working just an issue on my end, thanks though!

Comment: no problem mate, happy you could fix on your side too! have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw in another answer, you can `seek` a file position, provided you have opened the file in read/write more (`'r+'`)

```
with open("groupcount", "r+") as f:
  groupcount = f.read()
  i = int(groupcount)

  f.seek(0)

  f.write(str(i+1))
```

Note both answers use `with` when dealing with files.
`read` will pick up new line characters too, so this will only work if you just have a single number.

This will not work if you want to insert stuff in the middle of a file which would need subsequent data to shuffle forward.

Comment: absolutely correct! my solution was developed only after reading "the text file only contains the number which I am trying to change" in the comments of the question but better to explicit this good point as you did!